# Hash MD5 in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In Elixir you can get the md5 of a string:

```
ex(1)> :crypto.hash(:md5 , "Elixir") |> Base.encode16()
"A12EB062ECA9D1E6C69FCF8B603787C3"
```

But why does not return the same value from Terminal?

```
[~ ~]$echo 'Elixir' | md5
694f56f4b30e60837151723777795fc2
```

Sure I'm missing something.

Comment: It is recommended to not use MD5 anymore, but SHA instead. More background on this: https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/cryptographic-hash-functions-elixir-generating-hex-digests-md5-sha1-sha2/

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `echo` command will include a new line:

```
iex>:crypto.hash(:md5, "Elixir\n") |> Base.encode16()
"694F56F4B30E60837151723777795FC2"
```

You can use `case` to modify the case of [Base.encode16](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Base.html#encode16/2):

```
iex>:crypto.hash(:md5, "Elixir\n") |> Base.encode16(case: :lower)
"694f56f4b30e60837151723777795fc2"
```

---

You can use the `-n` flag with `echo` to prevent the new line:

```
$ echo -n 'Elixir' | md5sum
a12eb062eca9d1e6c69fcf8b603787c3  -
```

Comment: You cal also refer to https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/cryptographic-hash-functions-elixir-generating-hex-digests-md5-sha1-sha2/

Comment: md5 actually spits out binary data with non printable characters.  In order to make it readable virtually every program converts the binary into base 16, which is composed of the 16 characters (0-9, a-f).